# To prove that for any element a of a group G the center Z(G) is properly contain in the centraliser of a in the group G CG(a)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I has idea on abstract algebra, group theory ect. Ihave also check in the test block i have but could not get the solution. And also check the net but also no solution.

Comment: Compare the definitions for "center" with that for "centraliser", and become enlightened.

Comment: Containment need not be proper. Consider any abelian group.